My average output after using group by is not what i am looking for
I am trying to get average mpg values for each class from the dataset after using group by, however my output is giving me multiple values of class and I am looking for one average for each class.
How can I group my avg(unrounded_combined_mpg_ft1) so that it is taking the average for each class once?
this is the code I have:
--what are the top 5 most fuel efficient cars for a specific car type (sedan, suvs etc.)
select avg(unrounded_combined_mpg_ft1) as MPG, class
from fuel$
where fuel_type_1 <> 'Electricity'
group by unrounded_combined_mpg_ft1, class
order by unrounded_combined_mpg_ft1 desc


Sample Data and Desired Results (as text) please.   Otherwise this becomes a guessing game.

when you group by unrounded_combined_mpg_ft1 it becomes meaningless, since you also aggregate on it. Remove it from group by and change order by to AVG(unrounded_combined_mpg_ft1) DESC

You should only need to GROUP BY the class column, since you're averaging unrounded_combined_mpg_ft1.
select avg(unrounded_combined_mpg_ft1) as MPG, class
from fuel$
where fuel_type_1 <> 'Electricity'
group by class
order by MPG desc

